# inflating a xml to replace a non-viewgroup

Tags: android, layout, widget, custom-controls, inflate

I've been using compound components for a while with success. I face a little problem and wonder if there's a quick solution:

I need a custom seekbar, I have already have it as a style/theme, it's a pretty elaborated one, so I'd rather not replicate it by code. All seekbars are created programmatically as part of more complex blocks and it's not an option to change this.

Is there a way to, creating a XML just with a Seekbar and this style applied, "inflate" this xml into a compound class that just extends Seekbar?

The inflate functions accept only viewgroups, but their "replaceroot" version could well work for normal views also, it0s exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance

```
public class SeekBarYellow extends SeekBar {

    public SeekBarYellow(Context context) {
        super(context);
        construct_programmatically(context);
    }
    private void construct_inflating(Context context) {
        // how do I inflate a <SeekBar android:style=xxxx android ...>
        // into here? (R.layout.seekbar_yellow)
    }

    // i'd like to avoid this, by inflating R.layout.seekbar_yellow
    private void construct_programmatically(Context context) {
        Resources r=context.getResources();
        this.setThumb(r.getDrawable(R.drawable.scrubber_control_selector_holo_dark));
        this.setProgressDrawable(r.getDrawable(R.drawable.scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark));
        this.setIndeterminateDrawable(r.getDrawable(R.drawable.scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark));
        this.setMinimumHeight(13);
        this.setMinimumWidth(13);
        this.setThumbOffset(16);
        this.setPadding(16,0,16,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: if your seekbar has an "onDraw" method overriden, and all its functionality working, you can create an XML view of it, by creating an xml file and putting "com.yourpackage.yourapp.yourseekbar" as the class for the view : <com.package.app.seekbar android:layout_width="wrap_content" ..allparams /> and then inflate the xml

Comment: The seekbar is just the stock seekbar, but i want it with a different set of assets (theme). I can (and have) extended Seekbar with the idea of inflating into itself a layout with only the Seekbar and the Style attributes, but failed because inflate functions only accept viewgroups :(

Comment: can you post the code for your seekbar ?

Answer (score 1):

put this inside a seekbar_yellow.xml file in your layout folder, and inflate it using `inflater.inflate(R.layout.seekbar_yellow,null);`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  //<--- add this part
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation = "vertical">   
    <SeekBar 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark"
        android:minHeight="13dp"
        android:minWidth="13dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_dark"
        android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control_selector_holo_dark"
        android:thumbOffset="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

all this assuming the drawables are in your drawable folder, if they are in the android drawable folder you access them with @android/drawable/nameofdrawable

you can also include this file in other xml files by using

```
<include layout="@layout/seekbar_yellow"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, unfortunately I can't use Inflater.inflate because it needs a ViewGroup as the target, and Seekbars are not Viewgroups but plain views.

Comment: in that case, wrap it in a linear layout

Comment: hehe ... layout wrappings are not cheap, you are adding 3000 lines of code and an additional layer. This question is geared to discover if is possible to inflate non-viewgroups!

Comment: it is possible, i tried it, i dont know why you say it's not possible

Comment: You can inflate the seekbar from its parent layout, that's fine, but if you extend the class, I don't find a way to inflate the view replacing itself, I mean, to make the extended class self-contained so it will take care of inflating the layout, not its parent.